# Conversion failed when converting from a string to a uniqueidentifier

Tags: c#

When I run my code on debug I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting from a string to a uniqueidentifier

Here is the code:

```
public class UserObject
{
    private string m_name = string.Empty;

    public UserObject(string id)
    {
    #region Internal Logic
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(SiteConfig.ConnectionString))
            {
                string sSQL = "SELECT [UserName] FROM [aspnet_users] WHERE [UserID] = @UserID";
                using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sSQL, cn))
                {
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", id);
                    cn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader rd = cm.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rd.Read())
                        {
                            m_name = rd[0].ToString();
                        }
                        rd.Close();
                    }
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    #endregion Internal logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Is UserId a UniqueIdetifier in your table? If so what is the value if `id` when you debug?

Comment: have you tried Guid.Parse(id) ?

Comment: Do you *really* have a completely empty catch block, catching *all* exceptions? That's not a good idea, and may well be hiding what's *really* going wrong.

Comment: yes my UserId is a uniqueIdentifier and the id does not have a value..

Comment: check if the id is "string.empty" or "DBNull.Value" then create "guid.empty" and use it.

Comment: try using catch block and find it. That'll be grt*. Use ex.StackTrace and identify it....

Comment: `""` is not `null`!! `null` is `null` (which is not a valid `Guid`), `""` is an empty string, which is also not a valid `Guid`.

Comment: the id is string.empty...and i dont have much info on the guid.empty or how i can apply it..

Comment: I've added some code to my answer. This handles three cases: `id == null`,  `id == ""` and `id == valid Guid`. This should give you hints.

Comment: Guid test = new Guid(string.Empty);
            Console.Write(test);  try the above two line of codes and see what happens - this is how string.empty works with guid(gives you error).

Comment: And Empty guid is this one;             Guid mine1 = Guid.Empty;
            Console.Write(mine1.ToString());   outputs->00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: And even this gives you error - >             Guid check = new Guid();
            check = null;  "Guid cannot be null(is non-nullable)"

Answer (score 4):

You said in your comment to the question that `id` does not have a value when being passed into the method. From the database point of view, `uniqueidentifier`s can be `null` (`DBNull` in C#), but to achieve this, you'd have to leave out the parameter or set `DBNull.Value` explicitly.

In C#, `Guid` can not be `null` - so you must either provide `Guid.Empty` or a string that can be converted to a `Guid` in the call to `AddWithValue`.

**EDIT**
Sample code follows: Please note that given the SQL statement you use, you won't get any results for the `Guid.Empty` case unless you have a user the ID of which contains only `0`s. I suggest, you change the `where` clause of your SQL statement as follows:

```
WHERE [UserId] = ISNULL(@UserID, [UserId])
```

That way, you get all users when you pass `null`.

```
public UserObject(string id)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(SiteConfig.ConnectionString))
        {
            string sSQL = "SELECT [UserName] FROM [aspnet_users] WHERE [UserID] = @UserID";
            using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sSQL, cn))
            {

                if (id.Length == 0)
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Guid.Empty);
                else if (id == null)
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", DBNull.Value);
                else
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Guid.Parse(id));

                cn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rd = cm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        m_name = rd[0].ToString();
                    }
                    rd.Close();
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Guid.Empty?? not familiar with it, how can i use it?

Comment: Shown in my code. Basically: `Guid myGuid = Guid.Empty;`. Please note that `Guid.Empty` is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`;

Comment: Non-code specific answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940350/conversion-failed-when-converting-from-a-character-string-to-uniqueidentifier) but is probably relevant.