# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier - Two GUIDs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I don't understand why I can't insert this. I can't spot the problem. The error message is
*Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.*

The GUIDs are the ones that I got when I did a select from some other tables.

```
insert into [db].[dbo].[table] (myid,friendid,time1,time2) values
 ( CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'0C6A36BA-10E4-438F-BA86-0D5B68A2BB15'),
   CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'DF215E10-8BD4-4401-B2DC-99BB03135F2E'),
'2014-01-05 02:04:41.953','2014-01-05 12:04:41.953')
```

I use SQL Server 2012

The columns are

```
id        uniqueidentifier,
myid      uniqueidentifier,
friendid  uniqueidentifier,
time1     datetime nullable,
time2     datetime nullable
```

Comment: Any triggers on the table? What are the column datatypes? Those GUIDs are fine.

Comment: No triggers. Types are in the post, I updated it

Comment: No repro. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2361/1) please double check the table structure. You haven't accidentally made one of the time columns `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: The problem was that the ID column wasn't getting any value. I saw on @Martin Smith JS Fiddle that he declared the ID column with DEFAULT newid and I didn't.

Comment: Leave it as answer and I will vote it up! Thanks :)

Comment: Still don't understand how the INSERT statement in the question could lead to the problem - you're overriding the default so it shouldn't be a problem. Perhaps this is a lesson to include the actual insert statement that fails?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - They aren't inserting `id` explicitly. So if the default itself was something invalid such as `''` they would get that error.

Comment: @MartinSmith ah, I thought the "id" was "myid" - especially since the title also only talks about "Two GUIDs" - easily confused by bad column names.

Comment: Those are valid UUID4s - but are they GUIDs? (REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953207/1021819)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem was that the ID column wasn't getting any value. I saw on @Martin Smith SQL Fiddle that he declared the ID column with  `DEFAULT newid` and I didn't..

Answer (score 44):

MSDN Documentation [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql)

To add a bit of context to [M.Ali's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940482/3649914) you can convert a string to a uniqueidentifier using the following code

```
   SELECT CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'DF215E10-8BD4-4401-B2DC-99BB03135F2E')
```

If that doesn't work check to make sure you have entered a valid **GUID**

Comment: Correct, one root cause for errors is an invalid GUID. Check if it has the correct pattern and string length first.

Comment: As in GUID not UUID - OP's identifiers are UUID4s - you are saying these will not convert? If not, how does one convert them? (REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953207/1021819)

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID(),myid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
                , friendid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, time1 Datetime, time2 Datetime)
insert into @t (myid,friendid,time1,time2) 
values
 ( CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'0C6A36BA-10E4-438F-BA86-0D5B68A2BB15'),
   CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'DF215E10-8BD4-4401-B2DC-99BB03135F2E'),
   '2014-01-05 02:04:41.953','2014-01-05 12:04:41.953')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

**Result Set**  With out any errors

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║                  ID                  ║                 myid                 ║               friendid               ║          time1          ║          time2          ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ CF628202-33F3-49CF-8828-CB2D93C69675 ║ 0C6A36BA-10E4-438F-BA86-0D5B68A2BB15 ║ DF215E10-8BD4-4401-B2DC-99BB03135F2E ║ 2014-01-05 02:04:41.953 ║ 2014-01-05 12:04:41.953 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced this issue today while executing the SQL Command using `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` of EF Core 5.

**Bad** code: the `contactId` is placed inside the `'` `'`

`await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"UPDATE Contact SET Status = {(int)Status} WHERE Id = '{contactId}'");`

**Good** code: remove the `'` `'` from the `contactId` and it works

`await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"UPDATE Contact SET Status = {(int)Status} WHERE Id = {contactId}");`

Answer (score 3):

My problem was the "guid" which I thought was a "guid" was ***not*** a guid:

http://guid.us/Test/GUID

Thus, I rechecked the string that I entered and saw that I did not have a valid guid.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure that when you get data , it should be in correct format.
Since the data types are of  uniqueidentifier so it's correct format will be
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

For example, 6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF is a valid Uniqueidentifier value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check unique identifier column and you have to give a diff value to that particular field if you give the same value it will not work. It enforces uniqueness of the key.

Here is the code:

```
Insert into production.product 
(Name,ProductNumber,MakeFlag,FinishedGoodsFlag,Color,SafetyStockLevel,ReorderPoint,StandardCost,ListPrice,Size
,SizeUnitMeasureCode,WeightUnitMeasureCode,Weight,DaysToManufacture,
    ProductLine, 
    Class, 
    Style ,
    ProductSubcategoryID 
    ,ProductModelID 
    ,SellStartDate 
,SellEndDate 
    ,DiscontinuedDate 
    ,rowguid
    ,ModifiedDate 
  )
  values ('LL lemon' ,'BC-1234',0,0,'blue',400,960,0.00,100.00,Null,Null,Null,null,1,null,null,null,null,null,'1998-06-01 00:00:00.000',null,null,'C4244F0C-ABCE-451B-A895-83C0E6D1F468','2004-03-11 10:01:36.827')
```

Comment: Please try to use the formatting options for code when posting answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had an interesting variation on this.  I initially thought that I had an issue inserting into a uniqueidentifier field, based on this question and, the answers.  However, in my case, I was getting this error when inserting into a varchar field.  The value that I was inserting, contained some text that was a uniqueidentifier but, also contained other text.  It looked like SQL Server attempted to parse the text as a uniqueidentifier because it recognized that some of the text was a uniqueidentifier.  When I had first setup the insert statement, the issue was masked because I was wrapping the value with UPPER.  I subsequently altered the "fix", casting the value as varchar.

Comment: I was using the cast in concert with isnull and when values were null, I got the same error.  Now using [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead - it implicitly converts everything to strings and, replaces null with the empty string -

Comment: I think this is the exact problem I have - can you share your MWE?

Comment: hi @jtlz2. MWE - Minimal Working Example? I have moved on from that job so I could not replicate my exact code but my comment in 2022 describes the approach. Do you have a question about that?