# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having an issue with my T-SQL query here:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.application = 
            SUBSTRING(b.postdata,
                NULLIF(
                    PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]-[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]-%',b.postdata),0),36)
FROM [Lionel1].[dbo].[CSL_Logging_STAGE] a
INNER JOIN [Lionel1].[dbo].[CSL_Logging_STAGE] b ON b.Id = a.Id
WHERE 
    a.application LIKE '%000%' 
    AND a.postdata != '' 
    AND a.postdata IS NOT NULL
    AND a.http_method = 'post';
```

I have tried a handful of different castings for the GUID that is stored in the application column and I have also restructured the query to have a subquery but that makes no difference.

The error is

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Some of the VALUES I am trying to set to application are

```
NULL
0dab3646-a4ed-4b63-9441-11e27fa36df8
f6a5c360-635a-48e0-bf71-76ef0b865441
```

Comment: Test your query by changing the UPDATE to just a SELECT and see what value(s) you are trying to set application to.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what value I am trying to set application to.

Comment: why are you using a self-join?

Comment: I am using a join so I can avoid using a subquery

Comment: I ran the select and it is either setting a GUID string or a NULL

Comment: Application is defined as follows [application] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,

Comment: Well your error is telling you that your select is generating a string that cannot be used as a GUID.

Comment: Question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940350/conversion-failed-when-converting-from-a-character-string-to-uniqueidentifier

Comment: Piyush it is not a duplicate as I am getting values back

Comment: you have the same problem title as link, either change the Title, its confusing me at first sight

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://pastebin.com/7VNtevec)

Comment: I know abatishchev but when I run the update it doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I needed to do a better job matching the appkey.  It was grabbing extra data on a few of the compares adding quotes and extra characters which are not valid in a GUID.