# How to insert data into unique identifier column into SQL Server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, pypyodbc

I have a table that has a column of type `uniqueidentifier`. How do I insert the data into uid columns using pyodbc?

I am trying this code:

```
 cursor.execute("""
                   Insert into tablename (col1,col2)
                   values (?,?)
                """, 
               '67E616B4-7DBC-6D14-B0BA-0F7DE2F94AEE',
               '2E92D02D-B7DA-4DED-9816-26B2CF867FA2' )
```

`col1` and `col2` are of type `uniqueidentifier`.

I get this error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. (8169) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940482/5841306) answer your question ?

Comment: How do i do this using python?

Comment: I wanted to know if there are any python libraries to handle this situation? I used UUID library but that doesn't help much.

Comment: I was able to insert these values using pyobc 4.0.30, Python 3.7.1 and ODBC Driver 17. I wonder if the issue is due to a configuration in SQL server? Can you try to create a new table and insert them there?

Comment: I use python 3.6. Could you please share the code?

Comment: ```python
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE _test (col1 uniqueidentifier, col2 uniqueidentifier)').commit()
```

```python
cursor.execute(
"INSERT INTO _test (col1,col2) VALUES (?,?)",
'67E616B4-7DBC-6D14-B0BA-0F7DE2F94AEE',
'2E92D02D-B7DA-4DED-9816-26B2CF867FA2'
).commit()
```

Comment: The example you provided works directly for me. Sorry comments don't allow me to format code easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fast_to_sql`](https://pypi.org/project/fast-to-sql/) which is an improved way to upload pandas dataframes to Microsoft SQL Server such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"col1": ['67E616B4-7DBC-6D14-B0BA-0F7DE2F94AEE'],
"col2": ['2E92D02D-B7DA-4DED-9816-26B2CF867FA2']
})
    
 fts.fast_to_sql(df, "tablename", conn, if_exists="append", custom=None, temp=False)
```

where **append** option stands for inserting new values to the table

Comment: thank you! But this works for python 3.8+. I only have python 3.6. I cannot move to 3.8 for some reasons. Is there an alternative for this?

Comment: `df.to_sql('tablename', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False )` might be another option @MerajHussain